# Symfony Zip archive with files 0 ko

Tags: php, zip, symfony1

UPDATE RESOLVED :

```
$config_server = sfYaml::load(sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir').'/config/server.yml');
        $url_root = $config_server[sfConfig::get('sf_environment')]['url_root'];
        $path_root = $config_server[sfConfig::get('sf_environment')]['path_root'];
        $path_upload = $config_server[sfConfig::get('sf_environment')]['path_upload'];

        $zipname = 'file.zip';
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
        $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

        //on récupère la collection de pièces jointes
        $files = Doctrine::getTable('PieceJointe')->getPiecesJointes($id_pjs);

        foreach($files as $file){

            //on récupère le fichier
            $realfile =  $path_upload . $file->getPathPj() . $file->getNomPj();

            //on récupère le nom du fichier
            $filename = $file->getNomPj();

            $download_file = file_get_contents($realfile);
            $zip->addFromString($filename, $download_file);

        }

        $zip->close();

        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        readfile($tmp_file);

        return sfView::NONE;
```

When i run this script i download an archive with the files but the files are empty.

When i var_dump the variable $Downloadfile i get the full path of the file :

> string(140)
>   "C:/wamp/www/sigap/uploads/MI/appel_projet/clos/candidature_TEST_laureat_TEST2TEST8888888_suivi_projet/SIGAP_SFD_Evol_50341-Suivi_v00(3).docx"

It's seems that i don't get the file contentof the files.

Here the result in my computer when i extract the arhive :

[image]

What i'm doing wrong ? i just would like to get my files into an archive. thanks so much in advance for your help.

```
  $files = array();
                foreach($this->rapports as $ra){

                $files[] = $ra->getPieceJointe();

            }


            $config_server = sfYaml::load(sfConfig::get('sf_root_dir').'/config/server.yml');
            $url_root = $config_server[sfConfig::get('sf_environment')]['url_root'];
            $path_root = $config_server[sfConfig::get('sf_environment')]['path_root'];
            $path_upload = $config_server[sfConfig::get('sf_environment')]['path_upload'];


            $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zipName = 'depots.zip';
    $zip->open($zipName,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) {

        $Downloadfile = $path_upload . $file['path_pj'] . $file['nom_pj'];

        //var_dump($Downloadfile); 

        //die;

        $zip->addFromString(basename($file['path_pj']) , file_get_contents($Downloadfile)); 

    }
    $zip->close();

    header('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="' . $zipName . '"');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipName));
    readfile($zipName);

    return sfView::NONE;
```

Comment: Have you tried with other file types (plain .txt), or tried the ZipArchive `addFile` method?

Comment: i resolved the issue , i updated the post, thanks for your help sir !!!